# CSS - Which way is best to include CSS for web page performance?

Tags: html, css

We all know we have four way to add css in any webpage

**External**

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

**Embedded**

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
    color: maroon;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
```

**Inline**

```
<h1 style="color:blue;margin-left:30px;">This is a heading.</h1>
```

**Import**

```
@import url("mystyleSheet.css");
```

Can any one explain in the above four way to add css in web page which one is best and why ?

Comment: **External** is the best way! Its valid and easy to edit.

Comment: This is an opinion question.  What is the best way?  For modularity it might be @import.  For readability, external.  For performance it would have to be tested with different network browsers, different browsers, different browser versions and even different hardware configurations.  Then measurements could be performed for network latency, memory load, etc.

Comment: in a perfect world, embedding CSS for crucial parts of your website to load above the fold content is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

**Three Ways to Insert CSS**

There are three ways of inserting a style sheet:

```
External style sheet
Internal style sheet
Inline style
```

**Cascading Order**

What style will be used when there is more than one style specified for an HTML element?

Generally speaking we can say that all the styles will "cascade" into a new "virtual" style sheet by the following rules, where number one has the highest priority:

```
Inline style (inside an HTML element)
External and internal style sheets (in the head section)
Browser default
```

So, an inline style (inside a specific HTML element) has the highest priority, which means that it will override a style defined inside the  tag, or in an external style sheet, or a browser default value.

@import url("mystyleSheet.css"); is a method to import css file in other css file.

To read more Please follow [CSS How To](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Best method is:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

Because coding will be clean.

Internal style sheet will better for web page performance. because it decrease HTTP request.

Comment: @import method will add one more HTTP request.

Comment: I believe the question is right that there are 4 methods.  Since , all though it is an indirect way to import into an HTML page, when the parent CSS page is imported the child will be also imported.

Answer (score 0):

External Stylesheets are better for a number of reasons and is best way among all of these four. You can find more about this [here](https://robertnyman.com/2008/11/20/why-inline-css-and-javascript-code-is-such-a-bad-thing/):

> ...
>
> **Lack of caching**
>
> HTML code will never be cached. Contrary to that, external dependencies, such as CSS and JavaScript files, will be cached by the visitor’s web browser after the first visit – this means that instead of loading a lot of superfluous HTML code for every page in your web site the visitor visits, it will quickly retrieve all style and interaction locally from the web browser cache.
>
> ...

Comment: Nice reference, and I agree to a point.  I think CSS should be modular so linking to a parent CSS and having it import child CSS with specific purposes would enhance the modularity and therefore the maintainability while still taking advantage of the external references being cached.

Comment: Google Insights will tell you to inline javascript and css to improve your site performance.

Comment: I've definitely cached HTML before. Maybe that was correct 10 years ago when it was posted but it's not now.

Answer (score 0):

External is definitely the best way, and I will explain why.

Firstly, it's organized. A single CSS file to affect the entire webpage, your website becomes easy to change. Also, you get better performance because a user only has to download the CSS file once, and then every time they go to another page, their browser does not have to redownload the CSS again.

Inline is obviously bad for organizational reasons, no one wants to read that code. I've had people come to me for help with their code and show me inline CSS, and I will never read a billion lines of inline CSS.

Embedding is okay, it's a good alternative and sometimes I find myself using it when I'm making something small for fun, however, as I mentioned above, it drains performance. Every time someone navigates to a new page, the CSS has to be redownloaded by the user.

Importing is interesting, I have never used it myself, but I hear stories about it lacking performance. For example, preventing style sheets from being downloaded concurrently, so if you have multiple CSS files, then... well, good luck with that.

In the end, I have always used the external way to add CSS to a webpage, and I don't see any advantages for doing it any other way.

Comment: But in this case those css classes also loaded which is no used by B Page or C Page because we loading full CSS in Single Go

Answer (score 0):

From all 4 methods do not use **import** method at all as per as page performance is considered, because it takes considerably large time than other 3 methods.

Other 3 methods are good but their use is totally depend upon code sizes..

1. if your page contain **massive CSS classes** then use **External method** as it is always a good choice to render a page using external CSS. You can **minify** that CSS file also using [this service - cssminfier](http://cssminifier.com/) to decrease loading time.
2. If your page contains considerably less CSS classe then use **Embedded** method.

**Try to avoid inline method** as possible because your code gets messier after using that method.

**There is a single good advantage of using inline and embedded method is that, above the fold content gets rendered fast.**

You should go through some of below articles/resources...

1.[Enable Compression](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression)

2.[Optimize CSS Delivery](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery)

3.[Minify Resources](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources)

Answer (score -1):

It's not an easy question to answer, because the perfomance depends on many factors (complexity of CSS selectors, file size, code optimisation etc.).

However, In general we can see that Inline CSS is added to element much faster as when the document is loaded and it does not cache because HTML code will never be cached.

Answer (score -1):

Out of the 4 methods, linking external file to web page is the best method.

Its pretty organised and needs change only in a single file which is reflected across the whole website.

But the most important reason to have a separate file is speed. Once the file is downloaded, its cached in browser and thus, need not to be downloaded again.
To enhance and improve the website performance further, I would recommend using **Bundling** and **Minification** as well.

**Bundling** : It's a feature that allows you to combine or bundle multiple files in a single file. Thus for the first page load, number of HTTP requests will be less, hence improving performance.

**Minification** : Minification is a code optimization technique. It removes all unnecessary characters from source code without changing its functionality.

Link for Bundling and Minification : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification